# Trying to get SMS and MMS on Android - HTC issues

Tags: android, sms, mms

I'm trying to write my own SMS manager and I found many tutorials how to get SMS and MMS with URI and Cursor, but each try I'm getting problems I can't solve. Hope you help me a bit.
Okay, so I've been using "content://mms-sms/conversations/" which should work both for SMS and MMS. Of course not. This code:

```
final String[ ] projection = new String[ ]{ "*" };
Uri uri = Uri.parse( "content://mms-sms/conversations/" );
Cursor query = getContentResolver( ).query( uri, projection, null, null, null );

TextView text = ( TextView )findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
text.setText( Integer.toString( query.getCount( ) ) );
```

Return 13 **which is false**, because when I opened my standard android mailbox, I counted 18 conversations.

Second thing, also tried to get "address" from conversations:

```
final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
Cursor query = getContentResolver( ).query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
while( query.moveToNext( ) )
    System.out.println( "recv " + query.getString( query.getColumnIndexOrThrow( "address" ) ) );
```

Sometimes the address is a number, sometimes is a name, and sometimes is null. Why? How can I fix this?

Third thing, on many tutorials, in stackoverflow too, there is very simple solution how to get addresss from MMS. Just get cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( "address" ) ) from MMS and done. **Not here on HTC**. I tried this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver( ).query( Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null );
if( cursor.moveToFirst( ) ) 
{
    for( int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount( ); i++ ) 
        System.out.println( "SMS " + cursor.getColumnName( i ) ); 
}

for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        System.out.println( "***************************************************************" ); 

Cursor cursor2 = getContentResolver( ).query( Uri.parse( "content://mms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null );
if( cursor2.moveToFirst( ) ) 
{
    for( int i = 0; i < cursor2.getColumnCount( ); i++ ) 
        System.out.println( "MMS " + cursor2.getColumnName( i ) ); 
}
```

And it returned me:

```
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS _id
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS thread_id
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS toa
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS address
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS person
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS date
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS protocol
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS read
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS status
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS type
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS reply_path_present
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS subject
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS body
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS sc_toa
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS report_date
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS service_center
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS locked
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS index_on_sim
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS callback_number
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS priority
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS htc_category
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS cs_timestamp
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS cs_id
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS cs_synced
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS error_code
07-21 02:12:40.631: I/System.out(25221): SMS seen
07-21 02:12:40.641: I/System.out(25221): SMS is_cdma_format
07-21 02:12:40.641: I/System.out(25221): SMS is_evdo
07-21 02:12:40.641: I/System.out(25221): SMS c_type
07-21 02:12:40.641: I/System.out(25221): SMS exp
07-21 02:12:40.641: I/System.out(25221): SMS gid
07-21 02:12:40.641: I/System.out(25221): SMS extra
07-21 02:12:40.641: I/System.out(25221): SMS date2
07-21 02:12:40.641: I/System.out(25221): 
***************************************************************
07-21 02:12:40.641: I/System.out(25221): 
***************************************************************
07-21 02:12:40.641: I/System.out(25221): 
***************************************************************
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS _id
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS thread_id
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS date
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS msg_box
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS read
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS m_id
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS sub
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS sub_cs
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS ct_t
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS ct_l
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS exp
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS m_cls
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS m_type
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS v
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS m_size
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS pri
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS rr
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS rpt_a
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS resp_st
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS st
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS tr_id
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS retr_st
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS retr_txt
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS retr_txt_cs
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS read_status
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS ct_cls
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS resp_txt
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS d_tm
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS d_rpt
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS locked
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS htc_category
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS cs_timestamp
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS cs_id
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS cs_synced
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS seen
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS extra
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS phone_type
07-21 02:12:40.691: I/System.out(25221): MMS date2
```

So it means I have NO field "address" in MMS. So how can I get the address? I can only get thread, but half of conversation is invisible. It looks like it's impossible to code own SMS/MMS manager, there are so many bugs on the HTC.

There is an app on Google Play named "GO SMS Pro" which works fine on my phone. So it means **there IS a way to code it properly**. What do I do wrong? How can I fix it and get properly SMSes and MMSes?

Answer (score 0):

Change from "content://mms-sms/conversations/" to "content://mms-sms/conversations"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Uri    uri    = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
```